# Returning specified elements in an array/list without using a for-loop in Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list

I want to return a subset of elements from a list, where the subset is a non-sequential list. Can this be done without a for loop, and if so how?

So, for example, say I have the following list

```
myList = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048]
```

and I wish to have only a subset of these determined by an indexing array

```
indexArr = [0, 3, 7, 11]
```

I want something that would then return those elements as

```
In : myList[indexArr]
Out: [1, 8, 128, 2048]
```

This must have been asked somewhere on here already, but I can't find the right resource. Kindly point me in the right direction, and I'll take this down. Thank you.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the reason for avoiding a for loop? Any solution to this problem is going to have to loop over at least `indexArr`, even if the actual loop is hidden behind a standard library function.

Comment: Of course, a for loop can be pretty trivially converted to a while loop if the requirement is just literally that you can't use a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `operator.itemgetter` function. It returns a function that returns the listed indices.

For example:

```
>>> import operator
>>> f = operator.itemgetter(1,3,5) # Create function to return listed indices.
>>> L = [2,4,6,8,10,12]
>>> f(L)
(4, 8, 12)
```

In your case:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> myList = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048]
>>> indexArr = [0, 3, 7, 11]
>>> f = itemgetter(*indexArr) # * expands a variable into separate arguments
>>> f(myList)
(1, 8, 128, 2048)
```

You may also be thinking of a list comprehension, but its syntax looks similar to a for loop:

```
>>> [myList[x] for x in indexArr]
[1, 8, 128, 2048]
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be achieved with `map` and `lambda`:

```
def arrayFilter(listArr, indexArr):
    return list(map(lambda x: listArr[x], indexArr))


myList = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048]
indexArr = [0, 3, 7, 11]

arrayFilter(myList, indexArr)    # will output [1, 8, 128, 2048]
```

Of course, you should add validation to make sure that the indexes provided in the indexArr, are valid indexes in myList.